# servlet execution threw an exception - NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, json, servlets, tomcat7

i have my servlet code that reads json data and prints it. It was working properly but unfortunately my tomcat server crashed, so i uninstalled and reinstalled it. I have included all my servlet and json jar files in classpath. But still, i get this exception. Can someone figure out this ?

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
>   type Exception report
>
> message Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from >fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
>     ReadFile.doGet(ReadFile.java:58)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache >Tomcat/7.0.88 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.88

Comment: probably your JSON jar was in tomcat/lib

Comment: @jzz add your json jar in context lib

Comment: @Scary Wombat that worked thank you:)